# MongoDb shutdown does not remove mongod.lock

Tags: mongodb

I read a ton of documentation on what the mongod.lock file is, but the answer I'm cannot find is whether or not a clean shutdown should remove this file.

Actually what I was trying to do is to stop mongo while is running as a service using the following code as shown [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/shutdown/#dbcmd.shutdown) (Note I'm running on win 8.1 and mongo 2.6.4 is running as a service)

```
mongo
>use admin
>db.shutdownServer({timeoutSecs: 60});
```

this command outputs me:

```
2014-09-02T20:40:05.061+0200 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
server should be down...
2014-09-02T20:40:05.066+0200 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed
2014-09-02T20:40:06.068+0200 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061     No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2014-09-02T20:40:06.069+0200 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
```

While executing this command the mongod.lock file is flushed (passing from X kb to 0 kb), but not deleted. After this shutdown mongo restart fine every time without any error.

So does a clean mongo shutdown delete the .lock file or not?

Thanks, Max.

Answer (score 5):

`mongod.lock` with zero size means the server has been shutdown in clean mode.